# Moved updated site to live hosting, getting white screen on front-end and when trying to view CP login page

Tags: upgrade, blank-screen

I got an established site running locally on my computer and updated EE from 1.6.9 to 2.7.3. I also made other modifications to the site and it was working fine locally. I moved all the local site files to the live host and renamed the old stuff "system_old, themes_old, etc." like I was doing an upgrade. After everything was uploaded I changed the folder names and dropped the live DB and then imported the updated DB. I get a white page when trying to access control panel and the front-end of site. I have attached an image of the debug error I get. I can see the old local path is still there... I 99% sure my DB is connected ok, and all files have been uploaded. I haven't changed any paths yet, because I cant login to the CP...any ideas? I really need to get this working soon as my site is down :/

EDIT: I've managed to get rid of the PHP errors, but the Fatal Error belwo those is still there causing issues...any idea what that is from?

[image: screenshot of errors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From these errors it looks like the paths are pointing to folders that don't exist (because you're moving from a local setup to live). Have you ever used a multi-environment config like [Focus Lab's Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config)?

Since you can't log into the control panel and it *looks* like the issue has to do with paths, you could get the paths reconfigured using a multi-environment config. Focus Lab documented the installation process very well. I'd recommend looking into it.

Comment: Aaron, the paths aren't an issue anymore, but that last fatal error is still showing up...

Comment: Do you know what version of PHP your server is using? Is it older than 5.2? Apparently [DateTimeZone](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php) was introduced in PHP 5.2.

Comment: Thanks ,emailing EngineHosting now...it is an older account...

Comment: Aaron, PHP needed to be updated on the server, EngineHosting migrated my site last night and it's working fine now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You bet! Glad you're up and running, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you still have references to your local filesystem for both your **themes** folder and your **templates** folder.

These values might be set in your `config.php` file, or directly in the database. (If you set them via config, you can override any bad values in the database.)

Pop these in your `config.php` file to fix this up:

```
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = '/real/path/to/templates';
$config['theme_folder_path'] = '/real/path/to/themes';
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent suggestions by Derek and Aaron.

It could also be something much simpler -- try re-uploading ALL files and reset permissions. White screens can caused by corrupted files during transfer via FTP/SFTP.